# Override a member inherited?

Tags: c#, inheritance

Here is my class :

```
public class PrimtivePropertyProxy<T> : FrameworkElement
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    [....]
}
```

There already is a field Name in FrameWork element but still, I'd like to define a property name so that when I do :

```
myPrimtivePropertyProxy.Name;
```

it returns the Name I defined in my class, and not the one from FrameworkElement.
I know this is a complete hiding but, well, that's what I need to do !

Comment: So what happens when you try exactly that?

Comment: atm I got a warning that I'd like to remove : Warning 1 'Qb.PrimtivePropertyProxy<T>.Name' hides inherited member 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Name'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

Comment: I really don't get where I can place a "new" so that the warning will go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this what you want?

```
public new string Name
{
     get;
     private set;
}
```

Comment: ok thats it, tried it but didnt compiled and I was still getting a warning :/

Answer (score 0):

And to avoid the compiler's warning, use the `new` keyword.

```
public new string Name
{
    get;
    private set;
}
```